# whether I should go for a service or handlers? in android

Tags: android

I am creating a app that would fetch data from a website every 2 minutes ..

I need to know whether I can go for a service ?

I tried using handlers and threads but it stops after 3 or 4 hrs I already tried using Async task but it's not working out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use service because its always runs in background . Thread and AsyncTask and any other handlers not give guarantees to runs in background life time of applicatin.

Here you can find good tutorial for service.

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-for_04.html

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/02/double-life-of-service.html

Answer (score 0):

u use the service good option.because service is always running background process

if want know about the service

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

Best to use a service, actually the best option there is to it. Always consider the users of your application as they do not want to see all that incoming and outgoing flow of data.